# Parent class vtable failed to initialize, due to: VTable setup of type AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.Widget.CoordinatorLayout failed assembly

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, androidx, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to create a custom Bottomsheet inheriting from CoordinatorLayout. But I am getting this exception
System.TypeLoadException: Parent class vtable failed to initialize, due to: VTable setup of type AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.Widget.CoordinatorLayout failed assembly:Xamarin.AndroidX.CoordinatorLayout.dll type:CoordinatorLayout member:(null)

Strange thing is that i inherited it from  Android.Support.Design.Widget and not AndroidX. [Inspired from here][1].

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using XBottomSheet.Droid.Behaviors;

namespace XBottomSheet.Droid.Views
{
    public class XBottomSheetView : CoordinatorLayout
    {
        private AnchoredBottomSheetBehavior behavior;
        private NestedScrollView contentScroller;

        #region Properties
        public int PeekHeight
        {
            get
            {
                return behavior.PeekHeight;
            }
            set
            {
                behavior.PeekHeight = value;
            }
        }

        public int AnchorOffset 
        { 
            get
            {
                return behavior.AnchorOffset;
            }
            set
            {
                behavior.anchorOffset = value;
            }
        }

        public bool SkipAnchored
        {
            get
            {
                return behavior.SkipAnchored;
            }
            set
            {
                behavior.SkipAnchored = value;
            }
        }

        public bool SkipCollapsed
        {
            get
            {
                return behavior.SkipCollapsed;
            }
            set
            {
                behavior.SkipCollapsed = value;
            }
        }

        private View contentView;
        public View ContentView
        {
            get
            {
                return contentView;
            }
            set
            {
                if(contentScroller != null)
                {
                    contentView = value;
                    RemoveAllViewsInLayout();
                    contentScroller.RemoveAllViews();
                    contentScroller.AddView(value);

                    var prm = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                    prm.Behavior = behavior;

                    AddViewInLayout(contentScroller, 0, prm);
                    RequestLayout();
                }
            }
        }

        public Color BackgroundColor
        {
            set
            {
                contentScroller.SetBackgroundColor(value);
            }
        }

        private string state;
        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return state;
            }
            set
            {
                state = value;


                if (behavior != null)
                {
                    behavior.State = int.Parse(State);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public XBottomSheetView(Context context) : base(context) {}

        public XBottomSheetView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
            behavior = new AnchoredBottomSheetBehavior(context, attrs);
            

            contentScroller = new NestedScrollView(context);
            contentScroller.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGray);
            ContentView = new FrameLayout(context);
        }

        public XBottomSheetView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {}

        protected XBottomSheetView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) {}
        #endregion

        public void AddStateChangedEvent(EventHandler onStateChanged)
        {
            behavior.StateChanged += onStateChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: @Jason All the code is present in the Github Url I added in description. Kindly click on Inspired from here link and go to droid section. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Relevant code needs to be in the body of your post, not in a link to an offsite repo

Comment: @Jason I have added the code. Problem is that this class is not even initialized even if I try to use it in XML. this CoordinatorLayout I have used from Android.Support.Design

Comment: Does this happen still after you clean bin/obj folders?

Comment: Yes @Cheesebaron: I removed Bin/Obj, cleaned the projects , restarted VS everything. this doesn't seems to solve

Comment: Also check that you are not mixing Android.Support packages with AndroidX packages, that might also give you a bunch of issues.